# Как осуществить загрузку изображний в Delphi ?

Tags: delphi, изображения

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли загрузить на форму в Delphi анимационное изображение, т.е готовое изображение формата .gif?

Comment: Стандартными средствами - нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными компонентами нельзя.

Вот статья по этому поводу [Анимация GIF в делфи](http://www.programmersclub.ru/Анимация-gif-в-делфи/)

Comment: можно через компоненты Jedi

Comment: Если бы Вы посмотрели по ссылке, то поняли что это уже советовали :)

Answer (score 1):

Поддержка GIF появилась начиная с Delphi 2007, в раздел Uses достаточно добавить GifImg и TImage будет отображать анимацию. Для более старых версий Delphi нужно скачать [TGIFImage](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/).